# Виджет добавление контента в соц. сети

Tags: соцсети

Где можно достать скрипт/виджет добавление контента в соц. сети, типа:
[image]

Интересует только такого формата (пиктограмма с счетчиком)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например тут: [Блок «Поделиться» для вашего сайта](http://api.yandex.ru/share/).

UPDATE: Вы используете CMS для сайта? Если да, то какую.

Comment: CMS самописная

Comment: Боюсь, что тогда только вручную от каждого сервиса собирать скрипты.